# drupal site changes multiple title tags on load

Tags: drupal-7, metadata, page-title

My site is https://www.swiftdigital.com.au. Its built in Drupal 7 and uses Bootstrap 3 theme. The issue is with `<title>` tag. When I load the site in browser firstly it displays the correct site title that is configured for each page in admin and then after 1-2 seconds it changes the title to "Swift Digital - Contact". I am using Yoast SEO module and it seems like it doesn't have any effect on the `<title>` tag. I don't know where to debug for the issue.

Comment: First, there is a dedicated StackExchange platform just for Drupal related issues: [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com). Second, the Yoast SEO module is in fact altering your meta tags. Did you try to disable the module and see if the title is still changing?

Comment: I disabled the Yoast Module and cleared the cache but it didn't change anything.